# modal should remain same but content should only change on actions - bootstrap & AngularJS using UIRouter

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-router, bootstrap-modal

I have a Signup link in menu. When I click on that popup modal should open for some links (Signup using Facebook, Signup using Google, Signup using Email)

When I click on Signup using Email, popup modal should remain same but the content of modal should change (there is a form to fill and submit)

I am trying to do it using UI-Router nested states
But the content in modal is coming what I have for home page.

Here is my route.js code:

```
.state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "app/modules/home/views/homeView.html",
        controller: "homeCtrl"
    })
    .state('home.modal', {
        url: "/modal",
        onEnter: [
            "$modal",
            function($modal) {
                $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'app/modules/home/views/partials/homeModal.html',
                    size: 'sm',
                    controller: 'homeModalCtrl'
                })
            }
        ]
    })
    .state('home.modal.signup', {
        url: "/signup",
        templateUrl: 'app/modules/home/views/partials/homeSignupLinkView.html',
        controller: "homeSignupModalCtrl"
    })
    .state('home.modal.signupForm', {
        url: "/signupForm",
        templateUrl: 'app/modules/home/views/partials/homeSignupFormView.html',
        controller: "homeSignupModalCtrl"
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
```

Here is my controller.js:

```
home.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $modal){
    console.log('homeCtrl') ;
});

home.controller('homeModalCtrl', function(){
    console.log('homeModalCtrl');
})
home.controller('homeSignupModalCtrl', function(){
    console.log('homeSignupModalCtrl');
})
```

By debugging I am seeing that my **homeSignupModalCtrl** is not invoking at all...!
Can anyone help, where I am missing?

Comment: You never include in homeModalCtrl in the state controller

Comment: Eventhough I will include controller:homeModalCtrl, it is taking home page content only in modal. Please check updated code